# Gradient descent versus fixed point iteration

Tags: optimization, gradient-descent

### Fixed-point iteration

Say I have the iteration

$$x^{(k+1)} \leftarrow x^{(k)} + \alpha f(x^{(k)})$$

to find $x^\ast$, the root of $f$, i.e. $f(x^\ast)=0$, where $f:(a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$, $\exists f'$ on $(a,b)$, and $\{x \in (a,b):f(x)=0\} \neq \emptyset$. $\alpha$ is given constant.

---

### Gradient descent

Say $f$ is twice differentiable. Then we can find the root of $f$ by minimizing $F=  \int f$, and since we have $\nabla F(x^{(k)}) = f(x^{(k)})$, the minimizing iteration is as follows.

$$x^{(k+1)} \leftarrow x^{(k)} - \alpha_k f(x^{(k)}) $$

This is indeed very similar to the above fixed-point iteration, except $-\alpha_k$ is dependent upon $k$ such that

$$
F(x^{(k+1)}) < F(x^{(k)})
$$

thus $\alpha_k$ is usually found using the **line search**.

---

### Question

So are these two methods really **different**? In other words, is there any difference in convergence speed or stability?

Since I'm stuck at showing even one of those, I would like to ask for a help. Looking forward to learn about the potential dangers of regarding the above as same.

---

### Edit

The **fixed-point iteration** converges when absolute value of the derivative of the RHS function is less than 1, i.e.

$$
\left| 1 + \alpha f'(x) \right| < 1, \ \ \forall x \in X
$$

where $X$ is the set where the iterates and the root lie.

For the **gradient descent** case, the iteration converges when

$$
\left| 1 - \alpha_k f'(x) \right| < 1, \ \ \forall x \in X
$$

but the line search itself does not guarantee this convergence criterion.

Comment: In your first expression, set $f(x) = -10x$ and $\alpha = 0.2$. Start at $x=1$.  Will you converge at all?

Comment: @jbowman of course the convergence criterion for the fixed-point iteration is $|1 + \alpha f'(x)| < 1|$ for $x \in X$ where iterates and the root lie.